# Python function returning no value

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am not able to figure out why the below two print statements gives different
     results. can any one please explain me? i am just giving a small sample example. in the first print statement table is getting replaced by a special character and the second one gives correct one.

```
import re  

def tblcnv( str ):  
    rtval = re.sub("table", "chair", str)  
    return rtval  

rval = "<table is in the place where you sit daily "  
tblcnt = re.sub(r"<(table.*place)", tblcnv('\1'), rval)  

print tblcnt  
print tblcnv("<table is in the place where you sit daily")
```

Comment: Can you add the output you're seeing?

Comment: @thegrinner D:\Python>tbl.py ☺ where you sit daily <chair is in the place where you sit daily

Comment: The comment suppresses newlines - if you edit your post it will be more clear.

Comment: `D:\Python>tbl.py`     `☺ where you sit daily`    `<chair is in the place where you sit daily`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) manual it takes a function which "is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern". As those occurrences are actually match objects you are best of using a simple lambda expression which extracts the `group(1)` of the match objects and passes it to your `tblcnv` function.

```
import re

def tblcnv( str ):  
    rtval = re.sub("table", "chair", str)  
    return rtval  

rval = "<table is in the place where you sit daily "  
tblcnt = re.sub(r"<(table.*place)", lambda m: tblcnv(m.group(1)), rval)  

print tblcnt  
print tblcnv("<table is in the place where you sit daily")
```

Comment: it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for your valuable explanation.

Comment: Would you mind to accept this answer? I would love to see this green tick. Thank you and all the best learning the awesome programming language called python!

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
tblcnt = re.sub(r"<(table.*place)", tblcnv('\1'), rval)
```

probably doesn't do what you think it should. The call to `tblcnv('\1')` returns '\1' which is the smiley face you see and then it replaces the first chunk of your string with said smiley face.

Answer (score 2):

When defining tblcnt, you're passing tblcnv('\1'). '\1' is the string containing a single byte with value 0x01. So the result from tblcnv is that same string.

Comment: You might want `'\\1'` or `r'\1'`.